# Print Specific File in your Computer C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, document

I'm using WinForms. I have a button in this form. When the button is clicked I want the program to print a specific file every time i click on it.

My Problem is: My code does not print the specific file in my computer. It prints out a blank document.

Example: *Button click* prints document "C:\image.jpg" all the time.

```
    private void btn_Print_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSelection = true;
        printDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;

        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = @"C:\\image"; 
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

            private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks i added that @xPeke

Comment: I don't know how to print a specific file from my computer @xPeke

Comment: Is it possibly permissions related? Are you able to print C:\image using Windows Explorer outside of your program? I don't see any problems with the code you provided

Comment: It prints out a blank document @Krondorian

Comment: I could print C:\images outside of my program. Its my application. My program doesn't draw the images into the paper it always prints out a blank document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works. You may need to adjust it as needed, but this would be your starting point.

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f83aff78-44c1-465c-86b4-9e4e5a2d97e2/how-to-print-files-stored-at-your-local-hard-drive-in-c?forum=winforms

Make sure you have:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

here it is:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
      {
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\image.JPG";
            pd.OriginAtMargins = true;
            pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
            pd.DocumentName = filePath;
            pd.Print();
            pd.PrintPage -= pd_PrintPage;
        }
      }
    }

    public void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        string labelPath = ((PrintDocument)sender).DocumentName;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(labelPath), 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: And of course, please accept the answer if this works for you :)

Comment: The code I posted prints out the image itself. based on his comments in his questions, it was printing out a blank page. This code prints out the image.

Comment: I will, what is : pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage?

Comment: += is used to subscribe to events. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Comment: pd_PrintPage gives me red error lines. "The name pd_PrintPage dos not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need to make sure that the pd_PrintPage() method is scoped outside of the button_click() method